# Second Order non-autonomous ODE - prove the solution is unbounded on [0,$\infty$)

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working on the problem below and have a known error

[image]

I've basically "proven" that as $t \to \infty$ the solution decouples to negative infinity.  However, we have as assumption that $\phi (t) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$

Can someone find where I went wrong?

Comment: Can you add which textbook you use at this (if any...)?

Comment: It's a problem the professor gave us.  It isn't from a book as far as I know.

Comment: I have a suggestion for another proof (unfortunately not about your proof, since I am not familiar to the Gronwall's inequality), but you have to work out the details: with $y=\exp{P}$ you get a Ricatti differential equation, for which you already know a solution. So the Ricatti then can be reduced to a first order ODE in the unknown solution (the one you want to study the properties). For the latter, you can see here the details: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462075/how-to-solve-the-riccatis-differential-equation. Maybe this is useful to you...

Answer (score 1):

It is correct that
$$
\int_{s=0}^t a(s)e^{\int_0^t a(u)\,du}\,ds\,\le\,\int_{s=0}^t Me^{\int_0^t M\,du}\,ds,
$$
but you multiply the integral with $-\varphi_0'$ which might be negative. In this case, your inequality is false.

Comment: The integral form of Gronwall's inequality does not make assumptions as to the sign of $\alpha (t)$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality

Comment: So what? You have $\int_{s=0}^t a(s)e^{\int_0^t a(u)\,du}\,ds\le\int_{s=0}^t |a(s)|e^{\int_0^t a(u)\,du}\,ds\le\int_{s=0}^t |a(s)|e^{\int_0^t |a(u)|\,du}\,ds\le\int_{s=0}^t Me^{\int_0^t M\,du}\,ds$. As I wrote, the problem is the $-\varphi_0'$ in front of the integral. Note that if $0 < s < t$ then $-5s > -5t$.